# How can I list (ls) the 5 last modified files in a directory?

Tags: linux, list, terminal, limit, ls

I know `ls -t` will list all files by modified time.  But how can I limit these results to only the last *n* files?

Comment: Reverse the order `ls -lrt` might help somebody.

Answer (score 328, accepted):

Try using head or tail. If you want the 5 most-recently modified files:

```
ls -1t | head -5
```

The -1 (that's a one) says one file per line and the head says take the first 5 entries.

If you want the last 5 try

```
ls -1t | tail -5
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the shell represents the output of `ls` in multiple columns, but the output of `ls` is piped to following command with 1 file/dir at a time

Comment: This ignores the Total at the top: `ls -1t | head -n 6 | tail -n 5`

Comment: I don't see a total, but if there is one that would certainly work.

Answer (score 46):

The accepted answer lists only the filenames, but to get the top 5 files one can also use:

`ls -lht | head -6`

where:

`-l` outputs in a list format

`-h` makes output human readable (i.e. file sizes appear in kb, mb, etc.)

`-t` sorts output by placing most recently modified file first

`head -6` will show 5 files because `ls` prints the block size in the first line of output.

I think this is a slightly more elegant and possibly more useful approach.

**Example output:**

`total 26960312
-rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff   1.2K 11 Jan 11:22 phone2.7.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff   2.7M 10 Jan 15:26 03-cookies-1.pdf
-rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff   9.2M  9 Jan 16:21 Wk1_sem.pdf
-rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff   502K  8 Jan 10:20 lab-01.pdf
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 user  staff   2.0M  5 Jan 22:06 0410-1.wmv`

Answer (score 16):

Use `tail` command:

```
ls -t | tail -n 5
```

Comment: This gives the 5 oldest. You need to reverse the sort ( `ls -tr` ) or use `head` rather than `tail`, to get the 5 newest.

Answer (score 10):

By default `ls -t` sorts output from newest to oldest, so the combination of commands to use depends in which direction you want your output to be ordered.

For the newest 5 files ordered from newest to oldest, use `head` to take the first 5 lines of output:

```
ls -t | head -n 5
```

For the newest 5 files ordered from oldest to newest, use the `-r` switch to reverse `ls`'s sort order, and use `tail` to take the last 5 lines of output:

```
ls -tr | tail -n 5
```

Answer (score 2):

`ls -t` list files by creation time not last modified time. Use `ls -ltc` if you want to list files by last modified time from last to first(top to bottom). Thus to list the last n: `ls -ltc | head ${n}`

Comment: Which platform/version do you refer to? Can you provide a link? 
Looking at the [linux man-page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) yields the opposite of what you state: 
`-t     sort by modification time, newest first`

Answer (score 2):

None of other answers worked for me. The results were both folders and files, which is not what I would expect.

The solution that worked for me was:

```
find . -type f -mmin -10 -ls
```

This lists in the current directory all the files modified in the last 10 minutes. It will not list last 5 files, but I think it might help nevertheless

Answer (score -1):

if you want to watch as it process last five modified file and refresh in 2 secs and show total number of files at top use this:

```html
watch 'ls -Art | wc -l ; ls -ltr | tail -n 5'
```