# Linux - Recursively list all the zip files and keep only latest modified 5 files and delete the remaining

Tags: linux, shell, unix

In command line, How can we recursively find out all the zip files in a directory and its sub directories and keep only the latest modified 5 files and delete the remaining.

The files paths would be something like below:

1. basedirectory/2015/12/18/abc.zip
2. basedirectory/2015/12/18/def.zip
3. basedirectory/2015/12/18/ghi.zip
4. basedirectory/2015/12/18/jkl.zip
5. basedirectory/2015/12/08/mno.zip
6. basedirectory/2015/12/08/pqr.zip
7. basedirectory/2015/12/08/stu.zip
8. basedirectory/2015/12/07/stu.zip

Answer (score 0):

I have a way, but it involves several (easy) steps. There are probably more elegant ways of doing this, but here is how I know how. They come from a couple sources, which I list at the end of my answer. You will use the already installed utilites `cd`, `find`, `ls`, `rm` and `head`. it will involve a creating and executing two bash scripts.

1. Open a terminal and change into your base directory with `cd ~/basedirectory`

This sets up the following commands. It is important that you stay in this directory for the rest of the commands.

2. Type `find`pwd`-name *.zip > find_zip`

This creates a list of all the zip files with the full path relative to the directory you changed in to. Instead of printing them to the screen, it writes them to a find_zip file in the directory you changed into.

3. type `cp find_zip remove_old_zip`

This creates a second, duplicate file that you will later use to delete the old files.

4. Open the find_zip file in your favorite text editor. If you're not used to using any, you can use gedit. If you don't have it, install it with `sudo apt-get udpate && sudo apt-get install gedit`
5. Do a search and replace as follows (in gedit): search for `\n` , and replace it with `" \\n"`

This places the list of folders within quotes. the first backslash places a "\" at the end of each line, which means continue reading the next line and execute all the code together. The \n preserves the line endings. The last " puts a quote at the beginning of each line. You need the quotes to escape special characters like ' and ( that may be in your file name.

6. Create 2 new lines at the top of the file and type:

   ## !/bin/bash

   ls -lt \

The first line turns your file into a bash script. The second line will list all the files you found with the `find` command and order them by date.

7. Create a new line at the bottom of your file and type: `| head -5`. Save and exit the file.

`|` is a "pipe" that will take the output of the ordered file list that `ls` creates and feed it into the `head` command. The `head` command will list just the 5 most recently modified files and display or print them on your screen.

As a result of steps 5-7, your file should go from looking like this:

```
basedirectory/2015/12/18/abc.zip
basedirectory/2015/12/18/def.zip
basedirectory/2015/12/18/ghi.zip
basedirectory/2015/12/18/jkl.zip
basedirectory/2015/12/08/mno.zip
basedirectory/2015/12/08/pqr.zip
basedirectory/2015/12/08/stu.zip
basedirectory/2015/12/07/stu.zip
```

to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -lt \
basedirectory/2015/12/18/abc.zip \
basedirectory/2015/12/18/def.zip \
basedirectory/2015/12/18/ghi.zip \
basedirectory/2015/12/18/jkl.zip \
basedirectory/2015/12/08/mno.zip \
basedirectory/2015/12/08/pqr.zip \
basedirectory/2015/12/08/stu.zip \
basedirectory/2015/12/07/stu.zip \
| head -5
```

8. Type `bash find_zip` into in the terminal. With your newfound list of the 5 most recent files, open up the remove_old_zip file created in step 3.

You will also be turning this file into a bash script, but it will remove all but the five newest files.

9. Delete the lines in the `remove_old_zip` file containing the 5 files you want to keep.
10. Do a search and replace as follows (in gedit): search for `\n` , and replace it with `" \\n"`

This is the same as step 5.

11. Create 2 new lines at the top of the file and type:

    ## !/bin/bash

    rm \

This is similar to step 6 except that rm will delete the files still listed.

12. remove the final \ on the final line of the `remove_old_zip` file. Save and exit.
13. Type `bash remove_old_zip`.
14. Type `rm find_zip remove_old_zip`.
    This remove the two scripts, which are now useless since the files have been deleted.

sources:
[How can I list (ls) the 5 last modified files in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691359/how-can-i-list-ls-the-5-last-modified-files-in-a-directory)

http://www.geekinterview.com/talk/758-how-to-continue-to-next-line.html

[List files recursively in Linux CLI with path relative to the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245698/list-files-recursively-in-linux-cli-with-path-relative-to-the-current-directory)